# How do I add the same recipient as a carbon copy and as the receiver of the email using PHP mailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

The behaviour I am seeing is if the receiver of email has the same email address as the person who is carbon copied in the email, that person will not be CC'd(a.k.a carbon copied).

```
         $this->mail->addAddress("cesarg@abc.com", "Fleet Pro");

        $this->mail->addCC("cesarg@abc.com",'second person');
```

With the code above, only addAddress works. Nobody is carbon copied.

However, if the person inside the method `addAddress` has an email different than the person who is being carbon copied. It will work.

Why does this happen? How can I make this work?

Comment: What's the difference? They get the email, don't they?

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Why would you want one recipient to get multiple identical copies of the same message?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. It's pointless and wasteful, and consequently PHPMailer doesn't (and won't) support doing it.